# Not sending encrypted messages

Tags: ssl, postfix, smtp, email-server, ubuntu-16.04

My mail server appears not to send encrypted mail.

[Image of red padlock in Gmail indicating unencrypted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aar8I.png)

It seems like most of the information/tutorials focus on setting up TLS so that a client can connect, which I believe I have achieved. I've learned that in the config file, SMTPD is mainly focused on receiving mail. I believe I'm missing some SMTP parameters, have tried a few, but no luck.

This is from my postconf - n:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = localhost
myhostname = xxxxxx.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxxx/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxxxx/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC when I had this issue it was the     `smtp_tls_security_level = may` option. Don't set it to `yes` as that may prevent communicating with non-SSL'd SMTP servers (who knows why those are still out there?) Here's my working config -

```
root@darkstar:~/ # postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
milter_connect_macros = i j {daemon_name} v {if_name} _
mydestination = mail.example.info, node3, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = mail.example.info
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_milters = unix:/spamass/spamass.sock
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.info/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/ssl/postfix/dhparams.pem
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, eNULL, EXPORT, DES, RC4, MD5, PSK, aECDH, EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA, EDH-RSA-DES-CDB3-SHA, KRB5-DES, CBC3-SHA
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.info/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_exchange_name = /var/run/prng_exch
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf,mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

Comment: Hot dog! I added these two to my main.cf and it worked: smtp_tls_loglevel = 1 and smtp_tls_security_level = may

Comment: @NathanKrowitz - not sure what the log level would have to do with it, but there ya go!